Abaqus Python: Shell Loft
I'm new to Abaqus scripting with Python and need help automating the Shell Loft operation. I have five wires positioned in different planes along the z-axis. My goal is to perform Shell Loft using two consecutive wires, resulting in a total of four shell lofts. I'd like to automate Shell Loft process. Can anyone please help?
Wire curves image

Please provide a minimal reproducible example, of what you already tried and what step is causing issues/you do not understand. The stackoverflow community is not here to write code for you, but to help with specific coding questions.

I haven't done this before, but looks like you could use the ShellLoft method from the python scripting interface. The method takes a sequence of Edge objects, like the ones you have described, and performs the loft operation.

This isn't a valid answer; it's links to some documentation.
